# By, with, using or via here?

Tags: grammar, word-request, word-difference

> - So, what do you think of the application I finished yesterday? Would you correct anything?
> - I support your idea, but the client would appreciate it more if it was completed **by/with/using/via** other software.

What is the best choice here and why?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with **using**. Here are what I think are the problems with the other word choices:

- **by** - This makes it sound like the software did all the work, without any human intervention. The work was actually done *by* a human with the help of the software.
- **with** - This word kind of works in this context, but I think it's better to use **using** since **using** is a verb and thus indicates an action - **with** doesn't tell you what the person would be doing with the software (which is, of course, *using* it).
- **via** - This word sounds awkward to me in this context. It is mostly used as a synonym of "by way of", as in "I'm flying to Hawaii **via** California". It can also be used to mean something is like a stepping-stone in a less literal sense, as in "She arrived at the answer **via** brainstorming." In other words, I think you would mostly use this word when you are talking about a path (literal or figurative) to somewhere with any number of "stops" on the way. In this sentence, the software is not like a stop on the way, but is the thing the person is using the entire time they are working to complete the application.

Comment: Also, not part of your question, but there are two other corrections I'd make here:
1) Would you correct *anything* ? To me, *something* implies just one thing. *Anything* allows the possibility of multiple things being corrected.
2) if it *were* completed - this should use the subjunctive, rather than the indicative mood.

Answer (score 1):

I think it sounds correct **and complete** if you use:

> I support your idea, but the client would appreciate it more if it was completed **by using** other software.

because you need both a preposition (by) and a verb (using).